# Resolving model in Backbone.js - Call set with {silent:true} and trigger attribute change events?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, model, backbone.js

I have a chart model like this:

```
//PSEUDO
chartModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
     defaults: {
         year : 1970,
         selected = ["Sweden", "Denmark"]
     }
 }
```

I'd now like to set both year & selected:

```
chartModel.set({year: 1987, selected : ["Finland"]})
```

But before I trigger the model change I'd like to "resolve" the changes to this unstable model. So I pass silent:true and override the set method:

```
chartModel.set({year: 1987, selected : ["Finland"]}, {silent:true})

//Pseudo set override
set : function(attrs, options) {

  // Extract attributes and options.
  options || (options = {});
  if (!attrs) return this;
  if (attrs.attributes) attrs = attrs.attributes;
  var now = this.attributes, escaped = this._escapedAttributes;

  [...]

  datamanager.loadNewDataIfNeeded(oldModel, newModel, callback)
```

I'd specifically like a data manager to "diff" the old attributes vs the new before I trigger the change event:

```
 callback : function(){
      chartModel.change();
 }
```

Now - when I know that the right data is in place - I'd like the views to render.

... But my Sidebar view that is bound to change:selected does not render?

```
Sidebar = Backbone.View.extend({    
    initialize: function(){
        this.model.bind("change:selected", this.render);
    }
    render : [...]
});
```

**My questions:**

1. When triggering model.change() manually, why aren't the individual attribute change events fired?
2. Do I really need to override the model set method to achieve what I want to ("resolving the model when several attributes are changed at once") or is there a better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion based upon my understanding of what you are trying to do is this:

- Rarely or never override the set method; not sure why you feel you have to do it in this case.
- If you call the set method without {silent: true}, you should get events for change:year and change:selected and change.  But objects have to be bound to them to get them.  See the bind function.
- If you call the change function, only the change event is triggered.  The attribute level events are not triggered.

It sounds like you should not be overriding the set method and just assure that you have proper binding in those objects that have an interest in this model's changes.  Also, eliminate the silent: true passage.

Here's some code based upon your comment:

```
Thing = Backbone.Model.extend({

  initialize: function(attributes, options) {
    this.bind('change:a', this.calculateC);
    this.bind('change:b', this.calculateC);
  },

  canCalculateC: function() {
    return this.get('a') == someMagicalValueForA && 
           this.get('b') == someMagicalValueForB;
  },

  calculateC: function() {
    if (!this.canCalculateC()) return;
    var self = this;
    $.post('some/url', function(data) {
      var c = // extract value for c
      this.set({c: c});  // which triggers the 'change:c' and 'change' events
    });


  }
```

});

```
ThingView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function(options) {
    this.model.bind("change:c", this.render);
  }

  ...

});
```

where the model itself is binding to change events for the a and b attributes and handling those by checking to see if it can calculate c, then doing so, then setting the value of c based upon the Ajax return.  The model will then trigger 'change:c' for a view to observe.  I sketched in the view plumbing which would enable this.

This is untested code, but hopefully conceptually close.

Comment: Thanks for comments! Let's say my model has attribute C that depends on A and B. Setting a certain combination of A and B must trigger an async data load request - data from which we calculate C. Not until this is done, should C trigger its change event which causes views to re-render and the hash to be changed according to the selection. To achieve this, my idea was to update the attributes "silently" on set(), then resolve the consequences of these changes to the model and then trigger events for both set attributes and computed attributes. But there is surely a better way?

Comment: Thanks again for great input. The example will however become quite expensive when I, for example, set 10 attributes and want to calculate many interdependent attributes before updating views and hash. Suppose that the user wants to choose an example state in the "chart application". The set() method receives 10 different parameters and based on the interdependencies of these, data should be loaded, scales updated etc. When all this has been figured out it's time to trigger the change events. That's the kind of logic I'd like to implement ...

Comment: Then you probably want to just register for the change event and perhaps look at the changedAttributes function to determine if you need to make your server call.  I think you may now have all the concepts you need to solve this.