# Grouping Backbone model changes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In Backbone I'd like to make multiple changes to a model, and then only fire the event handler once at the end (to redraw the screen).  Is this possible?  Something like:

```
model.set("attr1",val1);
model.set("attr2",val2);
model.change();
```

or:

```
model.attr1 = val1;
model.attr2 = val2;
model.change();
```

There used to be a `model.change()` method, but it was removed, quoting the changelog: *"The Model#change method has been removed, as delayed attribute changes as no longer available*"

I don't know how "delayed attribute changes" worked before, but it seems a step backwards to have removed this ability?

Does anyone know of a workaround for it now?

Answer (score 2):

You can set multiple values at once

```
    model.set({attr1: val1, attr2 : val2});
```

or check out silent option.

```
model.set({attr1: val1, attr2 : val2}, {silent:true})
```

Some solution you could find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178369/resolving-model-in-backbone-js-call-set-with-silenttrue-and-trigger-attribu)

Comment: Hmm, either of those is ideal, but it looks like what I'd like doesn't exist :(  Your first suggestion would require me to keep track of all the changes being made in a queue somewhere and then apply them all at once at the end, and the second one wouldn't fire any events at all.  Thanks anyway!